# Unable to make the firefox extension click a button in the website

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am creating a firefox extension to automate a process. It is a set of actions but I'm trying to do it one step at a time, and I got stuck at the very first step.

I wanted a way to make the extension click a button in a tab but it is not.

Here's the manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Automate Click",
    "version": "0.1",

    "description": "Find a button on a certain website and click the button.",
    
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/autoCP-48.png"
    },

    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_url>"],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/autoCP-32.png",
        "default_title": "Automate Click"
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": ["click.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

And the click.js file:

```
function clickGetTask() {
    const button = document.getElementById("get_task");
    button.click();
}

clickGetTask();
```

I don't know much of js. Just trying to make an extension. I searched around how I can make the extension click a button, and the firefox page gave me just this. Am I missing something? Tell me anything else is necessary.

Thank You.